# Converting matrix of colors to image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, draw

I need to convert `List<List<int>>>` to an `dart:ui.Image`. I have an algorithm to convert an integer to a color. I tried to do this by drawing one-pixel rectangles on the `dart:ui.Canvas`, but it is about 100 times slower than I expected! `_getPixelColor` is the method by which I convert `int` to `Color`. Here is my code:

```
Future<void> matrixToImage(FField sourceMatrix) async {

  PictureRecorder p = PictureRecorder();
  Canvas c = Canvas(
      p,
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, sourceMatrix.length.toDouble(),
          sourceMatrix[0].length.toDouble()));

  Paint paint = Paint();

  for (int x = 0; x < sourceMatrix.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < sourceMatrix[0].length; y++) {
      int pixelValue = sourceMatrix[x][y];      
        
      paint.color = _getPixelColor(pixelValue / 40 / paletteLength + paletteOffset); 

      c.drawRect(Rect.fromLTWH(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble(), 1, 1), paint);

    }
  }

  Picture picture = p.endRecording();

  Image result = await picture.toImage(sourceMatrix.length, sourceMatrix[0].length);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can compute your `int` value to an `int` value that the `Image` class understands, you don't need the detour through canvas drawing.

Just use [Image.fromBytes](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image/Image.fromBytes.html) with the `.value` of the `Color` as the list of ints.

Comment: How can I convert Image from image library to Image from dart:ui library?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how the image data is stored in the list of INTs.

Generally, I like this package to manipulate images and display them:

https://pub.dev/packages/image

```
import 'package:image/image.dart' as im;

im.Image? img = decodeImage(bytes); // different-IMAGE class !

Uint8List uint8list = getEncodedJpg(img!,quality: 85) as Uint8List;


// ...

build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(child:
    Image.memory(uint8list) // material-IMAGE class !
  );
}
```